# How do I train Glove embeddings in gensim from scratch?

Tags: stanford-nlp, gensim

How do I train Glove embeddings in gensim from scratch? Can I use gensim for this?

Answer (score 2):

Gensim doesn't implement the GLoVe algorithm. But it does offer the very-similar word2vec algorithm, which also creates a "dense embedding" (aka high-dimensional vector with many varied nonzero values) for individual words. See:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html

And, the FastText algorithm which, for some languages & purposes, can offer better-than-random guess-vectors for words it's never seen before, based on substrings within those words:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html

Gensim's `KeyedVectors` class can also load sets of GLoVe vectors that were trained elsewhere, for applying those vectors to other tasks:

```py
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors

glove_kv = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(GLOVE_FILE, binary=False, no_header=True)
print(glove_kv['apple'])
```